# Avoid using ui-view in Angular ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

It seems like **Angular.js ui-router** *must* have `ui-view` in order to have the whole thing to work. Here is an example without `ui-view` and routing is NOT working (no alert): http://plnkr.co/edit/e1vzj6pDdqADKJ2LSsd3?p=preview

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.12"></script>
    <script data-require="ui-router@*" data-semver="0.2.8" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <a href="#/link">Test</a>
    <!--div ui-view></div-->
  </body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state("link", {
      url: "/link",
      resolve: {
        test: function() {
          alert("Triggered resolve /link");
          return true;
        }
      }
    });
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});
```

If you put `<div ui-view></div>` back in, it would work.

This is not big deal because I could leave that `ui-view` empty. I don't use `ui-view` (may sound strange) because `ui-view` replace DOMs. I just want to toggle my `container` instead of doing completed rip-and-replace.

1. Is it the right approach of leaving `ui-router` empty as a hack?
2. Is there a way to make `ui-router` NOT require `ui-view`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ng-show or ng-if to achieve toggling of dom elements. But I do get your point that sometimes you need to just use ui-router as an object oriented location management tool.

You can use the `ui-sref` attribute on your `<a>` instead of a pure href as a hack to get to a state  that doesn't know where to get rendered.

I edited your plunkr to demonstrate:

http://plnkr.co/edit/KLm8HTIkvnbGzhzmwSwG?p=preview

basically change

```
  <a href="#/link">Test</a>
```

to:

```
 <a ui-sref="link">Test</a>
```

I am not sure of best practices or anything. It is a good question and I am sorry I can't completely answer on the 1-st point that you made. Not sure if it is the right approach, it all depends on how you use ui-router. In a rather big app we have somewhat many named views and then we do use ui-view, but I can see how sometimes it would be useless.

Comment: Using `ui-sref` works and without `ui-view` directive in the HTML. I am curious why is that the case. Also how do I use `ui-sref` if I need to pass params as well, not just the `state`

Comment: i forked the plunk and created one for you that demonstrates how to pass params: http://plnkr.co/edit/L38Tz8CiUt4e4FV6Vmml?p=preview. I can see how in some situations that way of passing stuff to ui-router can be benefitial but in most situations I'd use pure hrefs. If you indeed don't need rendering of views, I'd still use an emtpy ui-view just cause html code looks neater.

Comment: baba, did you change anything in your plnkr code because I didn't see the code to pass params

Comment: Never mind, I figured out here http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref

Comment: @HP I had, in my comment